# How to prevent tap on AlertDialog area from passing behind?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dialog

I am using a `WebView` to show an embedded youtube video.

After that I show an `AlertDialog` that appears over that `WebView` and if I tap on the `AlertDialog` area, the behind  video will handle the tap events, such as playing, pausing, etc.

How can I prevent the tap on AlertDialog area from passing behind?

Next you can see an image of that sample App and its source code. There is a floating button that launches the `AlertDialog` with the text `"Ola Mundo"`. Then taping on the area of the `AlertDialog` will make the video start playing.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late double screenWidth;
  late double screenHeight;

  // Get the proportionate height as per screen size
  double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
    // 812 is the layout height that designer use
    return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
  }

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
  double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
    // 375 is the layout width that designer use
    return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
  }

  Uri getYoutubeUrl(BuildContext ctx, id) {
    return Uri.dataFromString(
        '<iframe width="100%" height="${getProportionateScreenWidth(screenHeight)}"'
        ' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$id"'
        ' title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" autoplay;"'
        ' allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        mimeType: 'text/html');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = mediaQueryData.size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Sample video")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: getProportionateScreenHeight(screenWidth),
          child: WebViewWidget(
              controller: WebViewController()
                ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.black)
                ..loadRequest(getYoutubeUrl(context, "HF05SHKi55g"))),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (ctx) => const AlertDialog(
                    content: Text("Ola Mundo"),
                  ));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Updated on 2023-03-01**

Related to Flutter Issue [PlatformView should support IgnorePointer widget on iOS](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89956)

Comment: `IgnorePointer`/ `AbsorbPointer` may help, it would be easier if you could https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have update OP with the image and sample code.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh `IgnorePointer`/ `AbsorbPointer` work fine on `WebView` loading a Web page, but don't work with embed youtube video on Ios. Apparently, it works with Android but not in Ios. I have opened an Issue on flutter https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121137

Comment: Related with Issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89956 - _PlatformView should support `IgnorePointer` widget on iOS_

Comment: @MiguelGamboa Hi bro! Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue but on Flutter Web because I'm using a video player that is platform view of the web.

Comment: @MehrozeZaidi No solution. Just a workaround. I start by displaying a video thumbnail (a Stack with the video image and a play button image) and after first tap, then I will replace it with the WebView with the embed youtube. Now the tap over the alert dialog is not handled by my  thumbnail and does not play the video.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa Thanks for the workaround, I appreciate  it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is still pending a solution for this Issue [PlatformView should support IgnorePointer widget on iOS](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89956) here it is my workaround in the meanwhile.

I start by displaying a video thumbnail (a Stack with the video image and a play button image) rather than the `WebView`, and after first tap, then I will replace it with the `WebView` with the embed youtube. Hence, the tap over the alert dialog is not handled by thumbnail and does not play the video.

The skeleton for this code is something like:

```dart
Widget _buildVideoSection() {
  return _videoInitialized
    ? _buildWebViewForYoutubeVideo()
    : _buildVideoThumbnail();
}
GestureDetector _buildVideoThumbnail() {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      if (!_videoInitialized) {           
        setState(() => _videoInitialized = true);
      }
    },
    child:Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox( /*... video image...*/ ),
        SizedBox( /**... play-button.png ...*/),
      ]
    ),
  );
}
```